# Seek method in ruby File object

Tags: ruby

Here's some code from Zed Shaw book:

```
input_file = ARGV[0]
def print_all(f)
    puts f.read()
end

def rewind(f)
    f.seek(0)
end

def print_a_line(line_count,f)
puts "#{line_count} #{f.readline()}"
end

current_file = File.open(input_file)

puts "First Let's print the whole file:"
puts # a blank line

print_all(current_file)

puts "Now Let's rewind, kind of like a tape"

rewind(current_file)

puts "Let's print the first line:"

current_line = 1
print_a_line(current_line, current_file)
```

In `rewind(f)`, `f`is a `File` type object. `File` is a subclass of `IO`. Implementation from `IO` of `seek` is defined like that:

```
seek(amount, whence=IO::SEEK_SET) → 0
Seeks to a given offset anInteger in the stream according to the value of whence:

:CUR or IO::SEEK_CUR  | Seeks to _amount_ plus current position
----------------------+--------------------------------------------------
:END or IO::SEEK_END  | Seeks to _amount_ plus end of stream (you
                      | probably want a negative value for _amount_)
----------------------+--------------------------------------------------
:SET or IO::SEEK_SET  | Seeks to the absolute location given by _amount_
```

There are two arguments (`amount` and `whence`) instead of one. In that case, is the second argument optional (Can't I tell from this definition)? Or is Ruby using another `seek` method (not from `IO`)? In that case, from which class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell from the definition if an argument is optional. If it is followed by `=` and an expression, then that argument is optional, with that value being the default. In this case, `whence` is optional.

To tell which definition in the hierarchy is used, use `owner`.

```
f.method(:seek).owner
```

will return the module whose definition is used.